AWS ALB Ingress Controller - SSE channel closed INTERNAL_ERROR
There is a microservice exposed by an Ingress using AWS ALB Ingress Controller so the flow is this one:

AWS Application Load Balancer
Ingress
Service
Pod/Micro SSE Channel

I am trying to reproduce via curl the following web error that multiplies over time with the web open:

So, if I do the curl from the Ingress private IP the connection keeps open:
root@ubuntu-pod:/# curl -X GET http://10.22.xx.xx:8080/myapp/sse/api/v1/events
data:{"message":"SSE channel opened"}

^C

However, accessing from the DNS shortly after the connection is closed, returning an error and replicating what happens on the web:
root@ubuntu-pod:/# curl -X GET https://mydnssite/myapp/sse/api/v1/events -N --insecure
data:{"message":"SSE channel opened"}

curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

Trying with the DNS from the ALB, same result:
root@ubuntu-pod:/# curl -X GET https://internalalb-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/myapp/sse/api/v1/events --insecure
data:{"message":"SSE channel opened"}

curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.9/guide/ingress/annotations/
I can't find any ALB Ingress Controller annotation that can handle this, only the timeout but at some point it expires so it is not the solution, how can I fix this?
